# TS2345: Argument of type 'Moment' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MomentInput'

Tags: angular

I am using moment js to convert date-time

> const start = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');

but I get the error:

> Argument of type 'Moment' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MomentInput'.
>     Type 'Moment' is not assignable to type 'MomentInputObject'.

Typescript: 2.4.1

Node: 7.10.0

npm: 4.2.0

Angular/cli: 1.3.2

moments: 2.19.3

Comment: Are you by chance using the moment-tz package? I have come across a similar issue where the types available for moment-tz aren't 100% compatible with those of moment (core).